# Set environment variables in runtime logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that is triggered by events from Azure Eventhub. Two environments are sending events to the same hub. I want to set environment specific URL based on the message from event hub. Environment can be either Fabrikam or Contoso.

Now I have tried to set both url's in template parameters. The variable is set to Contoso or Fabrikam right after the event, but the workflow definition parameter is not able to use variables('ApiBaseUrl')

Is there a way to set url environment this way?

Parameters file:

```
"Contoso": {
      "value": {
        "ApiBaseUrl": "https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/"
      }
"Fabrikam": {
      "value": {
        "ApiBaseUrl": "https://fabrikam.azurewebsites.net/"
      }
```

Logic app file:

```
"environment": {
            "value": {
              "ApiBaseUrl": "[parameters('variables('ApiBaseUrl')).ApiBaseUrl]"
            }
          }
```

Comment: Hi, may I know if the solution provided below works ? If still have any problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use the value of the variable as the key of the parameter to get the parameter value. Now the code of your parameter should be like:

```
"parameters": {
    "Contoso": {
      "value": {
        "ApiBaseUrl": "https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/"
    }
}
```

Please modify the parameters code above to:

```
"parameters": {
    "Contoso": {
        "defaultValue": "https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/",
        "type": "String"
    }
}
```

Then you can just use `parameters(variables('ApiBaseUrl'))` to get the result you want.

[image]

Comment: This does not answer the user's question. It is more on the lines of how to switch the values based on which environment the call is coming from. If the call is from Fabrikam then its ApiBaseUrl should be used else it should be taken from Contoso